# Is it possible to mix APFS and HFS+ volumes on the same physical disk?

Tags: macos, apfs, hfs+, hdd

I wish to have two volumes on a drive (not SSD); one HFS+, one APFS.

Would it be possible to have these on an HFS+ partition or APFS?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by volume and partition?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was very poorly phrased.

If having multiple volumes on the same disk, HFS+ and APFS, would it be better to format the disk itself as APFS or HFS+?

Comment: - this is on an external HDD fwiw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you would need a separate partition for each volume type. In other words, APFS type partitions can hold multiple volumes, but each must be a APFS volume. HFS+ type partitions can hold a single volume which must by HFS+ type.

In addition the first partition is usually a EFI type partition which contains a single volume of FAT32 type. So, you would need at least a total of three partitions on the drive.

> No single partition type can support both HFS+ and APFS volumes.

Comment: Thank you David. You answered the question I asked, but unfortunately I asked the wrong question.

Comment: @paxromana: Edit the question if you need to. Otherwise, delete the question and ask a new question.

Comment: I've posted a new question at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/347854/316475 . I'm leaving this question and marking as answered as I think your answer might be useful info for others.