# Disk format for HDD with both APFS and HFS+ volumes

Tags: macos, partition, apfs, hfs+, hdd

For a HDD which will have both HFS+ and APFS volumes, is it better to format the disk itself in Disk Utility (on High Sierra) as APFS or HFS+?

Comment: This is not how disks work. You will first need to partition the disk, and these partitions can be of different types. As the person in your other question already described. You cannot format a partition that is HFS+ with as APFS, that would make the partition an APFS portion instead. (a volume is basically a formatted partition that is mounted)

Comment: This is using Disk Utility, which I should have stated and have just clarified by editing my question. When erasing a disk in Disk Utility, before partitioning, one must choose the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by starting with a whole disk APFS partition, I believe.  I gave the whole disk to APFS, and then I followed the directions in this article to shrink the APFS partition:

https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/resize-your-apfs-container/

This freed up unused space on the disk, which I think I was able to assign to a new partition in HFS+ format using Disk Utility.  I needed to do this because I wanted to have a ZFS partition on the same disk with an APFS boot partition, and ZFS doesn't really interface with APFS (ZFS can replace an HFS+ partition, though).